# Monoing the output of the audio jack in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, audio, sound-card

I am using an audio mixer which only accepts mono inputs and I want to send the output of my MacBook Pro to it. I just wonder if it is possible to convert the stereo output of the audio jack to mono? That is, if the normal output for the two channels is `<a, b>`, I want to have `<a+b, a+b>` in the output. Is it possible to do such a thing with Soundflower?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Accessibility preference pane has an option to play all audio as mono:

[image]

Comment: I am using Mac OS 10.7 and it's a bit different. The option is under universal access->hearing. Thanks for your answer.